# I've just created a database using Visual Studio, how do I open this in SSMS?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I've created a database in my web application using Visual Studio. (Typical way of App_Data > Add New... Database etc.) But SQL Server Management Studio (that I have installed) allows me to do things that I cannot through Visual Studio. So I would like to open my database in SSMS, how do I do this??

Comment: If you want your questions to be taken seriously, perhaps rethink the joke name?

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: Your name is kind of similar to http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet , I think that's what @Oded was talking about.

Comment: @Oded looks like pure coincidence - Skon and Jeet are perfectly valid names. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Possibly, though not very common in the UK where both the OP and Jon Skeet are from...

Comment: @Oded many people migrate to the UK for college then work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find all that you need on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx), but here's the fast version:

1. Open SSMS
2. You should be able to connect to your local SQL instance
3. Right click the `Databases` folder
4. Add a MDF file that you created through Visual Studio (click the Add button and browse to your file).
5. Click OK, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the feedback. Seems simple enough. I got the impression that somehow 'attaching' in SSMS would create a new instance but I'm assuming anything I do no this attached database will affect the mdf file (which is what my project will continue to reference). Thanks again.